# How to do annotation processing and analyze the result with Junit test run status

Tags: java, junit, annotations

In my project I have created custom annotation which I have added to important classes and methods.

I want to process these annotation after running my junit test suites to check if my annotated methods are covered and how much coverage of those methods. How can I achieve this programatically?

Comment: What do you mean by _process these annotations_?

Comment: What I mean by processing is that , I have annotations which have run time retention. So after all my Junit tests are run I want to cross verify if all my annotated functions are passed or failed. Which classes , methods have no test cases.

Answer (score 0):

With [Google reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) you can analyze JARs (or the classpath) to find the methods decorated with your custom annotation.

Than you can inspect the output of JUnit and link data together. How to get the output of a JUnit run depends on how you execute your suites, but it should always be possibile to generate the report in XML format and then parse it (or directly use the API without messing with XML)

Comment: Thanks @Rafaelle but I want to do it inside my test suit , once test suits are run , I want to process the junit output and identify my annotated classes and methods and check whats the status of my annotated clases , passed , failed and have not test case. I dont want to do it as separate tool. I want to integrate this logic along with my test suite run to generate a final output.

Comment: So what? Sure the code must run after the suite. I just described one possible implementation